# Exporting html report of Android Lint from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I came to know that we can't export xml/html reports of Android Lint in eclipse. Is it applicable to Android Studio as well?

I want to export xml / html report of Android Lint (used by - studio - analyze - Inspect Code)..

When I run it through my macbook terminal it says - -bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory.

Let me know how can I resolve it.

Comment: do you have an executable gradlew file in your project, did you do cd YourProjectPath before calling your lint check?

Comment: do you have an executable gradlew file in your project - I am not sure, how do I cross-verify? did you do cd YourProjectPath before calling your lint check - yes, I am currently, in my project folder.

Comment: do you see gradlew appear in the result of an ls command?

Comment: ls gives me only - AndroidManifest.xml lint.xml,res,assets, proguard-project.txt, src,libs and project.properties

Comment: My bad..project was in different path, though downloaded path was different, thanks buddy!

Comment: Can you mark my comment as useful?

Comment: sure, how do i do it?

Comment: Also, I did not get answer - if I can export report from Android Studio?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The lint report from (./gradlew lint) is different than the Android Studio code inspection report (Analyze -> Inspect Code). It looks like it includes all the Android Lint items and lots of additional checks

Here are the steps to export the Android Studio code inspection report:

- Run Analyze -> Inspect Code
- Find "Inspection Results" window/panel

  - if it's not visible, try View -> Tool Windows -> Inspection Results
- In the inspection view, at left side, you will get an option symbol to export to html/xml and then, give the path where you want that file to be stored.

  - Note that the specified directory must exist

Comment: I am getting below error after clicking on export as HTML:

"There is not enough memory to perform the requested operation"

I have updated 
-Xmx - 1024 & XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize - 512

Could you please tell me, what could be the issue?

Comment: @smitha I am able export as xml but I want it as html, When I select html option and try to export I am getting error unable to open index.html and I see nothing is generated.. Any idea on this ?? Please help

Comment: I too getting above error. Getting an error while export as html.

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585 did you guys found solution? Even I am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

From the IDE window, you need to open the Gradle view, inside this view you'll see a section called all tasks, you can either click on `lint` or on `check`.

Comment: how do i open gradle view in IDE?

Comment: Inside the top menu: View>Tool Windows>Gradle

Comment: I got - All tasks. But how does - i get - lint or check? I do not see anything of that type or I am missing something!