# Lint HTML/PDF report

Tags: android, report, android-lint

I want HTML or PDF report for my android project, I've tried to generate HTML file following this tutorial, but its empty, while generating XML succeeds.

Note: The following stack overflow issue was used as a tutorial:
[Exporting html report of Android Lint from Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292337/exporting-html-report-of-android-lint-from-android-studio)

Is there any way to generate HTML or PDF report in Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `./gradlew lint` in the terminal from the root of your project.

After that you can find your html reports here by default: `app/build/reports/lint-results.html`